# didDiscoverPeripheral not called in background

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to poll the RSSI of 5 bluetooth le devices.  To do this without connecting to them (constraint on my system) I schedule a ble scan every so many seconds.  This works great when the app is in the foreground but when it goes into background mode it stops calling the didDiscoverPeripherals callback.  I have enabled background operation for bluetooth central role and am using a specific service UUID in my scan.  I have also tried connecting to and disconnecting from each of my peripherals before starting the scan as suggested in another post but still it's not working.  I'm using an iPhone 6+ on iOS9.3.3. Any clues?

Comment: How are you repeating the scan at intervals in the background?  The scan duplicates key is ignored in the background, so you will only receive a single call to `didDisocverPeripheral` per discovered peripheral.

Comment: When my app goes into the background I connect to one of my peripherals which then triggers a series of connects and disconnects. But apparently this idea of connecting and disconnecting to "forget" the peripheral doesn't work anymore so I'm stumped.

Comment: So, the peripheral initiates the disconnect?

Comment: No the appdelegate initiates the connect and the didconnectperipheral callback then initiates the disconnect.